# ¿Consulta de BD ? MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Hola amigos tengo un problema espero me puedan ayudar tengo mi LOGIN ya puedo registrar y me puedo acceder pero tengo 5 perfiles en mi base de datos pero solo puedo iniciar con 2 los demás no los encuentra por nombre ya revise el código pero no encuentro mi error porque la consulta solo encuentra dos datos y los demás los omite.
El sig. código es para acceder donde hace la consulta a la base para ver si esta el usuario solicitado después compara las claves y si esta bien lo redirige a otra pagina  **

```
<?php
//se lee la cookie de sesion
session_start();
//se establece una conexión a la base de datos
include 'conexion.php';
//se validarán los campos si la sesion aún no está abierta
if (empty($_SESSION) and isset($_POST['name_user'])){
    //se escaparán caracteres peligrosos
    $name_user=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['name_user']);

    $key_user=$_POST['key_user'];

    //se hará la consulta a la base de datos
    $consulta='SELECT * FROM RegistroUser where nombreUser= "'.$name_user.'"';

    //si hubo un resultado
    if ($ejecución_de_la_consulta=$conexion->query($consulta)){
        //se obtiene la contraseña registrada
        $contraseña_guardada=$ejecución_de_la_consulta->fetch_assoc();
        //se compara la contraseña
        $verificar_contraseña=password_verify($key_user,$contraseña_guardada['claveUser']);
        //si el resultado de la comparación ha sido verdadero
        if ($verificar_contraseña){
            //se asigna la sesión y redirecciona
            $_SESSION['nombre']=$name_user;
            header ('location: panelControl.php');
        }//si la contraseña es incorrecta
        else{
            session_start();
            session_destroy();
            header ('location: ./');
        }
    }//si el usuario no está registrado
    else{
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        header ('location: ./');
    }
}//si hay una sesion abierta o no se enviaron datos
else{
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header ('location: ./');
}
?>
```

[image: Muestra los datos Almacenados en la BD]

[image: Muestra Login Exitoso pero solo con los ID 4 y 5 (los datos no los encuentra y se coloca bien el nombre)]

[describe el problema visual](https://youtu.be/HBg2H97YX1M)

Comment: exactamente en qué parte del código marca el error? en traer al usuario, al momento de ingresar la contraseña o en dónde?

Comment: como tal el error no me arroja, pero tengo mi tabla 5 datos pero solo puedo buscar 2 para iniciar sesión los demás usuarios no lo encuentra como si no existiera y no manda a la pagina de panelcontrol

Comment: puse un video donde muestra visualmente la falla
https://youtu.be/HBg2H97YX1M

Comment: Tene en cuenta que muchisimos usuarios que podrian ayudarte no pueden acceder al video. El error debe estar claramente explicado en la pregunta.

Comment: Podrias agregar que usuarios encuentra, cuales no, y como es la query ($consulta) de los usuarios que no encuentra. tene en cuenta que hasta un espacio en el nombre al guardar en la db puede ser la falla

Comment: Puede que las contraseñas no sean las correctas y por eso no entra. Prueba con contraseñas sencillas primero, sin caracteres especiales y eso.

Comment: todas las contraseñas son "root"
    //se hará la consulta a la base de datos
    $consulta='SELECT * FROM RegistroUser where nombreUser= "'.$name_user.'"';